# Creating Two Time-Dependent Array Like Datasets for Keras LSTM Model in R

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm

I am working on a time series forecasting project using a Keras LSTM - CNN model in R, and I need help creating two specific datasets for model training. My data spans from 2007 (week 26) to 2021 (week 25), in total 728 time steps, and I want to create two different inputs for the model:

1. **Initial Phase Data**: This should include data from week 26 of the previous year to week 8 of the current year. Each year from 2007 to 2021 should have its unique initial phase dataset, so in total 14 'initial phases'.
2. **Previous 3 Weeks Data**: This dataset should consist of the data from the 3 weeks preceding the week I want to predict.

I want to start predicting weeks from week 8 in 2021, which would be timestep 35. So each target week depends on its initial phase and the previous 3 weeks.

The input data has the shape (week, latitude, longitude, channel) and the target data (week, latitude, longitude).

I am struggling with the correct way to slice and structure these datasets. Below is my current approach for the initial phase data:

```r
input_data <- array(rnorm(3669120), dim = c(728, 45, 56, 2))
target_data <- array(rnorm(198744), dim = c(728, 13, 21))

initial_phase_data_list <- list()

# Iterate over each season
for (year in 2007:2021) {
    # Calculate the start and end index for the initial phase of the season
    start_index <- 1 + (year - 2007) * 52
    end_index <- start_index + 25

    # Extract the initial phase data for the season
    season_data <- input_data[start_index:end_index, , , ]

    # Add the extracted data to the list
    initial_phase_data_list[[length(initial_phase_data_list) + 1]] <- season_data
}

# Concatenate all seasons' initial phases into a single array
initial_phase_data <- do.call(abind::abind, c(initial_phase_data_list, along = 1))
```

For the second input:

```
previous_3weeks_data_list <- list()

# Iterate over each season
for (year in 2007:2021) {
    for (week in 26:52) {
        # Calculate the start and end index for the 3 previous weeks
        start_index <- 1 + (year - 2007) * 52 + week - 4
        end_index <- start_index + 2

        # Extract the 3 weeks data
        weeks_data <- input_data[start_index:end_index, , , ]

        # Add the extracted data to the list
        previous_3weeks_data_list[[length(previous_3weeks_data_list) + 1]] <- weeks_data
    }
}
# Concatenate all data into a single array
previous_3weeks_data <- do.call(abind::abind, c(previous_3weeks_data_list, along = 1))
```

And then something like this:

```
# Create dataset for initial phase (26 weeks)
initial_phase_dataset <- timeseries_dataset_from_array(
  data = initial_phase_data,
  targets = target_data,  # Adjust if you have corresponding target data
  sequence_length = 26,
  sequence_stride = 1,
  batch_size = 32,
  shuffle = TRUE
)

# Create dataset for previous 3 weeks
previous_3weeks_dataset <- timeseries_dataset_from_array(
  data = previous_3weeks_data,
  targets = target_data,  # Adjust if you have corresponding target data
  sequence_length = 3,
  sequence_stride = 1,
  batch_size = 32,
  shuffle = TRUE
)

# Input shapes based on your data
input_shape_initial_phase <- c(26, dim(initial_phase_data)[2], dim(initial_phase_data)[3], dim(initial_phase_data)[4])
input_shape_previous_3weeks <- c(3, dim(previous_3weeks_data)[2], dim(previous_3weeks_data)[3], dim(previous_3weeks_data)[4])
```

**Questions:**
I am very unsure on how to do this, I am unexperienced with keras (and python) and wouldn't know for example how to expect the keras tensors and batch datasets in Rstudio, to check if they were correctly initialized.

1. How can I effectively create these two datasets, ensuring they are correctly structured for an LSTM model in Keras?
2. What is the best approach to align these datasets with my target data for training?

- My `input_data` array is 4-dimensional, but I'm unsure if I'm slicing it correctly for the LSTM model.
- I am using the TensorFlow and Keras libraries in R.

Any ideas and help are highly appreciated!

Just to include everything, here is the rest of my attempted model approach:

```r
# Define the model with two inputs
input_initial <- layer_input(shape = input_shape_initial_phase)
input_previous <- layer_input(shape = input_shape_previous_3weeks)

# LSTM layers for each input

inputs <- layer_concatenate(list(input_initial, input_previous), axis = -4)
  outputs <- inputs %>%
  layer_conv_lstm_2d(
    filters = 32, 
    kernel_size = c(3, 3), 
    padding = "same",
    return_sequences = TRUE
  ) %>%
  layer_dropout(0.2) %>%
  layer_conv_lstm_2d(
    filters = 32, 
    kernel_size = c(3, 3), 
    padding = "same",
    return_sequences = FALSE  # Return only the last frame
  ) %>%
  layer_dropout(0.4) %>% 
  layer_conv_2d(
    filters = 1, 
    kernel_size = c(3, 3), 
    padding = "same",
    activation = 'linear'
  )


# Create the model
model <- keras_model(inputs = c(input_initial, input_previous), outputs = outputs)

# Compile the model
model %>% compile(
  optimizer = 'adam',
  loss = 'mean_squared_error'
)

# Print the model summary
summary(model)
library(deepviz)
plot_model(model)
# Train the model

history <- model %>% fit(
  x = list(previous_3weeks_dataset, initial_phase_dataset),
  y = list(outputs),
  epochs = 10
)
```